# How to change session scope properties using ognl?

Tags: java, jsp, session, struts2, ognl

Is it possible to change session scope properties using `ognl`?

For example, if I have on my session an attribute called `PROCESS_CONFIG` which is an object with an attribute `name`, how can one change this attribute `name` on a JSP?

I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
<s:textfield value="%{#session.PROCESS_CONFIG.name}" id="PROCESSNAME" name="#session.PROCESS_CONFIG.name"/>
```

When I submit the form and access the session object in my action, through `ServletActionContext.getRequest().getSession().getAttribute("PROCESS_CONFIG")`, the attribute `name` has not changed.

**EDIT:**

The object saved in session as `PROCESS_CONFIG`, is a very deep complex object (composed by numerous references to other objects, with lists of lists of objects) and on my view I just want to present a **very tiny subset** of its attributes (including attributes from its composed objects). So, polluting my JSP with all other fields as hidden is impractical! The view in question is a form where one can change the value of those fields and I would like to **directly and automatically** update the object saved on my struts 2 session, `PROCESS_CONFIG`, as if `PROCESS_CONFIG` object was a property of my action. For example, given the previous code snippet, `PROCESSNAME` is an attribute of `PROCESS_CONFIG` object and I would like to update it automatically in `PROCESS_CONFIG` object instead of having an  `PROCESSNAME` property on my action and then having to explicitly do the setting of `PROCESSNAME` on my 
`PROCESS_CONFIG` object.

Comment: Whether or not you can, I'm not sure you should-the view layer is for view stuff, the Java side is for logic.  What's the use case?

Comment: Concurring with Dave, I would be curious about your requirement that leads you to need to do this from the jsp?

Comment: Regardless of it being a good idea, the obvious thing to try would be an assignment with the equals sign, which works btw. If you want a painfully obvious example see: http://commons.apache.org/ognl/language-guide.html and search the page for the work "assignment" if you want a new value in a map, that too should be addressed there. Good advice would be to read the whole page from top to bottom and then follow best practice and ONLY use property look up and evaluation of Boolean statements using OGNL.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I've edited my post and I hope it clarifies my problem. Basically, my idea is to avoid of having to do the plumbing in my action of getting attributes from properties and then set them to my struts 2 session scoped object.

Comment: @theeDude That doesn't really explain why you want to do this in the view layer, though: *presenting* objects from the session has nothing to do with *setting* session values.

Comment: @DaveNewton Ok, you made me think a bit further and I think I got your point.. I totally forgot about the prepare method.. I am not able to try this right now so i ask: if in my action I have a property say, "process", and if on the prepare method I assign that variable the the object in PROCESS_CONFIG, and if on my view I have <s:textfield value="" name="process.name"/>, it would work, right? I mean, in my action the "process" property would have the attribute name changed and I would have the other attributes filled as they are on my PROCESS_CONFIG object, correct?

Comment: @theeDude I don't understand your last comment at all, there is a big difference between changing a properties name (I don't think you should ever try to change the names of properties on your action) and setting the value of a property (something that is very reasonable). Explain what you are trying to do and what result you want, we can help from there.

Comment: @Quaternion I dont know where did you get the idea that I wanted to change properties names. Of course, that is absurd. All I ever said was that I wanted to present the values of some of PROCESS_CONFIG object's attributes on a form (the view) and, as a result of the submit of that form, to change the respective attribute's values on my PROCESS_CONFIG object as if that object was a property of an action, that is, without me having to explicitly do the plumbing by calling the PROCESS_CONFIG object's respective attribute setters on my action's method. Is it clear now?

Comment: Well, I thought here's only one problem with using a session but it's also binding problem, in S2 form fields are bound to action attributes by name not by value.

Answer (score 1):

The session in S2 is a map where you could put the attributes before you use it with OGNL in the JSP. To have this working around let your action implement the `SessionAware` and look at the official [site](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/http-session.html) for the description and usages, and read [How do we access to the session](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/how-do-we-get-access-to-the-session.html) from the FAQ.

To your question: why didn't you get the attribute in JSP. Because you are using S2 and OGNL to get it (via `#session` reference) and you didn't put the attribute to S2 session. S2 session implementation differs from the standard http session. However, if you set attribute to the standard http session you can still access it in JSP 2.0 manner.  The opposite is also true.